# Elasticsearch Aggregation , Scripted Field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

`Date            Queries        Sales
01/10/2016   100              10
01/11/2016   100              10
01/12/2016   100              10
01/13/2016    200              5
01/14/2016     50             15
01/15/2016   100              10
01/16/2016    200              5
01/17/2016     50             15
01/18/2016   100              10
01/19/2016    200              5
01/20/2016     50             15
01/21/2016   100              10
01/22/2016    200              5
01/23/2016     50             15
01/24/2016   100              10
01/25/2016    200              5`

i need to get a queries/sales % per day.
i will use scripted field to get that. will it work?

Now i need to get % per week.
Date histogram of week, with scripted field will work?

Now , i need to calculate rate of sales.
Which is sum of  sales whole week / number of days in week.
Number of days in week can change based on holidays
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Any solutions out there? Looks like simple task for aggs + script.